# How to make a fake coordinate to a point column through factory?

Tags: php, laravel, database, faker

I'm try to make a fake data through factory that contains a `point` column.

The coordinate column in migration:

```php
$table->point('coordinate');
```

I've tried in factory:

```php
'coordinate' => DB::raw("Point(" . fake()->latitude() . " " . fake()->longitude() . ")"),

'coordinate' => "Point(" . fake()->latitude() . " " . fake()->longitude() . ")",

'coordinate' => fake()->latitude() . " " . fake()->longitude(),

'coordinate' => [fake()->latitude(), fake()->longitude()],
```

Is there any way to fake coordinate with `point` column or using raw sql in factory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try it with [`ST_GeomFromText`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-wkt-functions.html)

```
'coordinate' => DB::raw("ST_GeomFromText('POINT(" . $this->faker->latitude . " " . $this->faker->longitude . ")')"),
```